# img in Safari gets hidden

Tags: html, css, web, safari

I have three icons (links with images inside) on my website that I want to link to my GitHub, Linked In and email accounts. It works fine on Chrome but for some reason Safari adds a bunch of styles to the Linked In icon that make it hidden.

Here's the code for the three links (the links have been changed):

```
<a href="http://github" target="_blank">
    <img src="img/github.png" alt="GitHub">
</a>

<a href="http://linked in" target="_blank">
    <img src="img/linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn">
</a>

<a href="mailto:me@mail.com">
    <img src="img/email.png" alt="E-mail">
</a>
```

This is the styling for the links (I'm using SASS so the styles are nested):

```
a {
    position:relative;
    padding-right:25px;
    padding-left:25px;

    img {
        width:64px;
        height:64px;
    }
}
```

In Chrome, this works exactly the way I want it to, when I inspect the page, this is what it shows:

[image]

But for some reason, in Safari, the Linked In icon is hidden, and the inspector shows this:

[image]

The inspector shows this for the Linked In image:

```
<img src="img/linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn" style="display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important; opacity: 0 !important; background-position: 0px 0px;" width="0" height="0">
```

Any thoughts on why Safari is doing this, and how I could fix it would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you have some kind of Ad/Social Media Blocker running in Safari?

Comment: Yup, that was exactly it, don't know why I didn't come across that initially, but oh well, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh! I had AdBlock installed on Safari, and that was blocking the image. Disabled AdBlock and it works just fine.